# Hidden field not updated in updatepanel after putting listview into insert mode

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I'm currently having a problem where a hidden field whose value is set in the code-behind does not propagate back to the client. The basic layout is as follows:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ..... 
<ContentTemplate ....
    <input id="myHiddenField" type="hidden" value="" runat="server" ....

    <asp:ListView ID="MyListView" .....
```

I have a button with an on click event, in there I set the hidden field value. If I don't put the listview into insert mode, the value is propagated back to the client; however, if I do put the listview into insert mode, then nothing. I'm also rebinding the datasource on the listview.

```
void mybutton_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    myHiddenField.Value = "testing";
    MyList.InsertItemPosition = InsertItemPosition.FirstItem;
    MyList.DataSource = // my datasource
    MyList.DataBind();
}
```

Side Note: I'm rebinding the listview so that the data bound delegate can be called and I can do extra stuff in there.

Comment: Fixed hidden field value not propagating back to client. As it turns out, I had a typo in my insert validator in the insert item template of the list view control. I had commented out the update panel, and ran with out it, asp.net throw an error alerting me to the issue. With the update panel, no errors were displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `<input id="myHiddenField" type="hidden" value="" runat="server"` use a `<asp:HiddenField ID="myHiddenField" runat="server" />` and everything should be fine.